# Why is setDate() and after toISOString() not working?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to subtract from the present day two days (`today - 2`);

The output should be as follows:

> YYYY-MM-DD

I get the above format of the **present day** with `.toISOString()` and `split()`.

```
today.toISOString().split("T")[0];
```

but when I do:

```
today.setDate(today.getDate() - 2);
```

My date ain't formatted. Why?

Below my code and outputs:

```
const today = new Date();
console.log(today.toISOString().split("T")[0]); // Output: 2021-03-12
today.setDate(today.getDate() - 2);
console.log(today); //Output: Wed Mar 10 2021 09:15:18 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)
today.toISOString().split("T")[0];
console.log(today); // Output: Wed Mar 10 2021 09:15:18 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)
```

Comment: You should `console.log(today.toISOString().split("T")[0]);` again, not `console.log(today);`.

Comment: I am an idiot. Thanks :D.
So the solution would be:

`let today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate() - 2);
today = today.toISOString().split("T")[0];`

Comment: `today.toISOString()` will *return* a formatted date. It doesn't set the formatting of the date object because there isn't one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the formatted date to get the required date :

```
const today = new Date();
console.log(today.toISOString().split("T")[0]); 
let newdate = today.setDate(today.getDate() - 2);
console.log(newdata); 
let newdatetwo = today.toISOString().split("T")[0];
console.log(newdatetwo);
```

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, it is because of a misplaced variable.

It should be able to be done like this:

```js
const date = new Date();
const reducedDate = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 2);

console.log(new Date(reducedDate).toISOString().split('T')[0])
```

Remember that `toISOString()` returns a string, not a date object.

Answer (score 1):

It is working, just printing the wrong output

```
const today = new Date();
console.log(today.toISOString().split("T")[0]);
today.setDate(today.getDate() - 2);

console.log(today.toISOString().split("T")[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let date = new Date();
let vorVorGestern = date.toISOString(date.setUTCDate(date.getUTCDate()-2)).split('T')[0];
console.log(vorVorGestern); // 2021-03-10
```